# How can I validate that a field is either empty or a number?

Tags: ruby, string, validation, ruby-on-rails-3, numeric

I want to validate if a received param is either an empty string or a positive number. I tried with:

```rb
validates :my_field,
  presence: true,
  if: ->{
    ((my_field.is_a? String) && my_field.empty?) ||
    ((my_field.is_a? Numeric) && my_field > 0)
  }
```

but it doesn't work. I can still either put non-empty strings and negative values. How should I do it?

Comment: What is the data type of the attribute in the database? With do you need to support both type with the same attribute?

Comment: _"How should i do it?"_ – mixing strings and numbers doesn't seem right in the first place. What are you trying to achieve? Can you give some context or show some examples? Your model probably has a fixed type according to its database schema. Since Rails will typecast any value, you should write your validation for the declared type only.

Comment: BTW, since you tagged your question with `ruby-on-rails 3` – that version of Rails is over a decade old and reached end-of-life in 2016. If this is you actual version, you should strongly consider upgrading the code base.

Comment: Tip: Instead of `(x.is_a? String)` try `x.is_a?(String)` to help encapsulate arguments correctly.

Comment: You probably want to validate the field once converted with `to_i` or `to_f`. Don't be picky about the exact type, but do get particular about the resultant value.

Comment: `(my_flield.is_a? String) && my_flield.empty?)` is a complicated way for `my_flield == ""`

Comment: Newer versions of Rails have a lot of built-in validations that address your needs. You might also want to think about whether you can just chain #blank? or #positive? to your roll-your-own validations if available in your Ruby or Rails versions.

Comment: @spickermann SQLite doesn't enforce certain type checks, and a lot of folks new to Rails aren't aware that all user input is a String or how convention-over-configuration applies to that input. I agree that the use case is not well defined, but the core question about how to handle unknown input types is something I would certainly expect a new Rails programmer to ask.

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR

Ruby on Rails 3 is *really* old, and while you may get an answer that works on Rails 3, it's long past end-of-life and so are the versions of Ruby that it ran on. My answer will assume Ruby 3.2.2 and Rails 7.0.4.2, but you can certainly adapt it to older versions to the extent that the features you want are supported or are willing to roll your own compatible implementations.

### Preface: User Input is Always a String

In Ruby on Rails, [ActiveRecord validations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html) of the sort you're using are generally a model concern. However, user input from HTML forms is always a String unless unless your model, view, or controller is coercing it before passing it onto some other part of the application.

There are a lot of different places in your application that you might put your logic, but best practice is generally to put such logic in the model. ActiveRecord takes care of a lot of the coercions for you, which makes it the simplest and most reliable solution here. There may be reasons to do additional validations or coercions elsewhere in the MVC stack too, so I'll try to give at least some light coverage to those options as well.

### Best Practice: Model Validations

#### Model: Using ActiveRecord Validations

If you follow the historical best practice of "fat model, skinny controller" then you can do one or more validations within your model. An example might include running multiple validations. You can do this with one variable validation per line, or use a list of validations on the same line.

Note that many validations also accept a Hash of keyword parameters for additional checks. Consider the following, which uses the [:allow_blank](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#allow-blank) and [:numericality](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#numericality) validations in recent versions of Rails.

```rb
class Foo < ApplicationRecord
  validates :my_field,
    allow_blank: true,
    numericality: {
      only_integer: true,                                                       
      greater_than_or_equal_to: 1
    }   
end
```

You can test this within `rails console` like so:

```rb
Foo.create(my_field: "").save!
#=> true

Foo.create(my_field: nil).save!
#=> true

Foo.create(my_field: "1").save!
#=> true
```

---

###### Sidebar: Handle Nil Values Appropriately for Your Database

The :allow_blank validation also accepts a literal `nil` value in addition to an empty String. Some databases such as SQLite will not coerce the nil into a String for you; results can vary with other databases, although many will raise an exception if the field's type definition doesn't allow `null`.

If you want to ensure you don't store a literal nil value in a database-agnostic way, then you'll either need to exclude nils by setting the [:allow_nil](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#allow-nil) Hash value to `false` in the validation above, or add a [#before_save callback](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.4.2/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks/ClassMethods.html#method-i-before_save) to coerce the nil into an appropriate String value before saving it to the database.

---

With the bang methods, a failed validation will raise:

> Validation failed: My field is not a number (ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid)

You can adjust the various validations and make changes to the messages returned or exceptions raised if needed, but chances are that this will be enough to get you going, and will suffice for your immediate needs.

### Other Options

#### View: Use Constraints on Your Form

You could do something like this in your view or partial:

```
<input type="number" name="my_field" min="1"/>
```

This would ensure that one couldn't enter a value into the form of less than one. There are lots of other HTML and JavaScript validations you could do, but ensuring that users can't enter a negative or non-integer value in the first place is a good start. It will still be a String when the controller gets the response, but at least it will already be in a coercible format.

#### Controller: Coerce String to Integer

In your controller, you can also take values returned by the user and coerce them before calling ActiveRecord methods on the values. I'm not 100% sure that recent versions of Rails don't do some of this automatically for you based on the field type, but if they don't you can simply use some really basic Ruby. For example:

```rb
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def create
    # Coerce the value, even if #blank?, to an
    # Integer. Note that if the param is #blank?
    # then #to_i will return +0+. #abs ensures
    # the value is positive.
    @my_field = params[:my_field].to_i.abs
  end
```

This approach won't guarantee that the user put in a valid value. It just ensures that the value is either zero or a positive integer. You *could* also ensure that it's never less than the minimum value with something like:

```rb
@my_field = params[:my_field].to_i.abs
@my_field = @my_field.nonzero? ? @my_field : @my_field.succ
```

This solves both problems, but doesn't actually prevent the user from entering invalid data or not entering anything at all. It just ensures the variable holds the right sort of data before you call any model methods.